# Re-exporting symbols in a typescript module declaration

Tags: typescript

I have a private JavaScript module that I wish to write type declarations for.  The structure looks like this:

```
.
├── index.d.ts
├── index.js
├── lib
│   ├── submodule.d.ts
│   └── submodule.js
└── package.json
```

In `lib/submodule.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'mymodule/lib/submodule' {

    class Submodule {
        // details omitted
    }

    export = Submodule;
}
```

In `index.d.ts` I need to re-export the `Submodule` class from `lib/submodule`.  Additionally I need to document a shortcut constructor declared at the top level.  Here is my attempt:

```
declare module 'mylib' {

    // export a `createSubmodule` function that is just a shortcut for new Submodule()
    import * as Submodule from 'mymodule/lib/submodule';
    function createSubmodule(): Submodule;

    // Also re-export Submodule
    export * as Submodule from 'mymodule/lib/submodule';
}
```

It seems that in `index.d.ts` the declaration for `submodule.d.ts` cannot be found.  The message received for both the import and export is: `Could not find a declaration file for module 'mymodule/lib/submodule'`

What is the correct approach for re-exporting a symbol like this?

Answer (score 0):

I found I needed to do two things:

1. Add inline references to the `d.ts` files
2. Use commonjs style imports

The code becomes:

```
/// <reference path="./lib/submodule.d.ts" /> // <= reference the path to the dependency

declare module 'mylib' {
    import Submodule = require('mymodule/lib/submodule'); // <= import = require()
    function createSubmodule(): Submodule;
    export * as Submodule from 'mymodule/lib/submodule';
}
```

Although this works I'm slightly uncomfortable about the `///` directives because elsewhere in the TypeScript docs it says these should be avoided in declaration files.  Perhaps I misunderstood that part.